# Odoo 14 Change value of input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, odoo, erp

I am calling an api from python that returns json to the javascript function. When returning the data I am setting the value of an input field using jquery. But when saving theform the field value is not being saved. What's the solution? Thanks in advance.

```
$.each(data['payload'], function(key, val) {
    let el = $('[name='+key+']');
    el.val(val);
});
```

Comment: @CherryDT Cool. It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes websites use form fields only as "frontend" for some internal state that gets synced whenever the data in the field changes.

When a user changes the contents of the field, a `change` event is fired. This won't happen if you programmatically change the value though, so such a change would not be picked up by code listening for changes.

To fix this problem, you can manually trigger a `change` event on the field after modifying its value. You seem to be using jQuery, there you can simply use the `change()` method like this:

```js
el.val(val).change()
           ^^^^^^^^^
```